# How could I search references to a field on a AST or a CompilationUnit in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scope, design-patterns, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

> Hi,
>
> I'm developing an Eclipse plugin. I
>   need to find all the references in the
>   source using AST's or `jdt.core.dom`
>   or something like that. I need this
>   references like `ASTNodes` in order to
>   get the parent node and check several
>   things in the expression where
>   references are involved.
>   Thanks beforehand.

---

Edited:

I want to concrete a little more, My problem is that I try to catch some references to a constant but... I have not idea how I can do to catch in the matches this references. I need check **the expressions which the references to a determined constant are involved**. I only get the source of the method where they are used.

I think the problem is the scope or the pattern:

```
pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern(field, IJavaSearchConstants.REFERENCES);


scope = SearchEngine.createJavaSearchScope(declaringType.getMethods());
```

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used something like:

1. Search for the declaration of an
   method, returns an IMethod
2. Search for references to the
   IMethod, record those IMethods
3. For each IMethod returned, create an
   AST from its compilation unit

Searching for declarations or references looks like the following code.

```
SearchRequestor findMethod = ...; // do something with the search results
SearchEngine engine = new SearchEngine();
IJavaSearchScope workspaceScope = SearchEngine.createWorkspaceScope();
SearchPattern pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern(searchString,
            IJavaSearchConstants.METHOD, IJavaSearchConstants.DECLARATIONS,
            SearchPattern.R_EXACT_MATCH);
SearchParticipant[] participant = new SearchParticipant[] { SearchEngine
            .getDefaultSearchParticipant() };
engine.search(pattern, participant, workspaceScope, findMethod,
                monitor);
```

Once you have your IMethod references, you can get to the AST using:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
if (methodToSearch.isBinary()) {
    parser.setSource(methodToSearch.getClassFile());
} else {
    parser.setSource(methodToSearch.getCompilationUnit());
}
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

See http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_int_core.htm for more details on java search, the java model, and the AST.

Comment: The point is... I don't understand how you iterate with the results (the 3rd point). How do you make a iteration block to do something with each result?. Thanks and sorry for my English!

Comment: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=192205 for my example of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your code but... I think the problem is in the scope I have. I need to look for statements but I have this scope: " scope = SearchEngine.createJavaSearchScope(declaringType.getMethods());" How could I get the statements instead of the methods? in fact... Is it possible?