# Replacement for deprecated items in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently on a task, where I need to fix the deprecated items in the existing projects. I mean I have to replace the deprecated items with the corresponding replacing items as given in javadocs,

Eg: `java.util.Date.setSeconds(int)`:  Instead of this deprecated method, we need to use `Calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, int seconds)`.

I need to automate this using java code in eclipse IDE, by giving a project name in the workspace as input.

Kindly suggest me in doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the search & replace functionality of your IDE, by utilizing regex. (your parameter values should be captured with regex)

There isn't any specific utility to replace deprecated code, because it is not always that case that there is a straightforward replacement. Sometimes there is not replacement, and in other cases there is a completely different approach.

Comment: Hi Bozho, Thanks for your comment. Is there any class or some source in java which can give the replacement of the deprecated items. If that is available I can just utilize it otherwise is there any other method to do this. I can go for regex, but I need to do a generic functionality which will just remove the deprecated items and replace it with the available replacement. Is it possible?

Comment: generically - no. there's too much variation.

Comment: Usually the @Deprecated annotation gives you a pointer to the API that supersedes the deprecated one.

Comment: yes, you can know which ones are deprecated, but not how to replace them.

Answer (score 0):

If the project is not really big probably easiest way is to do this by hand. It also handles the situations where there is no direct replacement.

Alternative (and definitely more interesting) way would be to write an eclipse plugin that extends eclipses JDT. Also if you are on Java 6 one possibility is to use [Java compiler API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

Comment: Hi Ahe, Is there any utility that will give the the replacement for the deprecated item if we are passing the deprecated item. Or is there any possible way for creating the utility by ourselves.

Comment: As @Ahe mentioned, you could use the JDT search APIs to find all references to setSecond(*), get the AST for that method, and use ASTRewrite to "refactor" the code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887132/how-could-i-search-references-to-a-field-on-a-ast-or-a-compilationunit-in-eclipse/5887882#5887882 for an example.

Comment: HI Ahe/Paul, I want a generic functionality which will replace all the  deprecated items in the given project. I too was trying to develop a plugin, but I dont find a source which will provide the replacement for the deprecated items. Kindly suggest your ideas.

Comment: @Paul Webster HI Ahe/Paul, I want a generic functionality which will replace all the deprecated items in the given project. I too was trying to develop a plugin, but I dont find a source which will provide the replacement for the deprecated items. Kindly suggest your ideas

Comment: As answered in your other question, there's no generic way to do this as there is no well defined format to `@Deprecated` that would allow a tool to change the code, especially for semantic changes.

Comment: As @Paul Webster said there is way too much variation to do this fully automatically +  there could be @Deprecated markings on your companies internal API also. By writing your own program you can probably handle few most common situations. But as I said, in the end the easiest way is probably to handle each deprecation by hand. Good IDE will help you to find all the places you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 4.30 (Q4 2023) could help. It includes:

> ### [Cleanup and quick fix to replace deprecated method calls](https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.30/jdt.php#deprecated-cleanup)
>
> A new cleanup has been added to the Source > Clean Up > Source Fixing tab page to replace deprecated method calls with inlined content. Choosing this option will inline
> the implementation of the deprecated method if and only if:
> The deprecated method has Javadoc that specifies a @deprecated tag which ends with "use `{@link ...}`" or "replace by `{@link ...}`"
> The `{@link ...}` tag refers to a method
> The linked method is actually called in the implementation of the deprecated method
> Methods and fields accessed in the linked method are visible at the location it will be inlined (e.g. using a package private method is ok to call if in same package)
>
> For example, cleaning up the following:
> [image: deprecated method call to inline -- https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.30/images/deprecated-before.png]
>
> will result in inlining the deprecated foo() call in foo2:
> [image: result of deprecated method call inline -- https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.30/images/deprecated-after.png]
>
> The functionality is also available as a quick fix for an individual call to a deprecated method that is marked with warning or error. One can also select a deprecated method call and initiate as a quick assist (select call and click CTRL + 1).